# Создание потоков в java и вывод приоритета

Tags: java

Написать программу, которая будет создавать 10 потоков (выводится номер потока и его приоритет).

Comment: День добрый. С чем конкретно у вас возникли проблемы при решении задачи?

Comment: Вообще не знаю как создать , а нужно прям сейчас

Comment: Герберт Шилдт, глава 11 многопоточное программирование прочитай, так ты лучше усвоишь материал

Answer (score 1):

Если ты хочешь работать с потоками на низком уровне, тебе нужно создать класс, работу которого ты будешь параллелить, допустим, `MyParallelClass`. Дальше у тебя два самых очевидных пути:

1. Унаследовать его от класса `Thread`.
2. Реализовать интерфейс `Runnable`.

Второй вариант более правильный, поэтому далее я буду рассматривать его.
После того, как ты заимплементишь `Runnable`, нужно будет реализовать метод `run()`, внутри которого уже и будет логика, выполняемая потоком. Если тебе нужно, чтобы поток выводил свой номер(id?) и приоритет, то выглядеть это будет примерно так:

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " " + Thread.currentThread().getPriority());
}
```

Далее, в своем методе main нужно создать пулл потоков, ограничивающий создание потоков десятком:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

И остается последний шаг, создать эти потоки(и не забыть их после выполнения работы убить)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    service.execute(new MyParallelClass());
}

service.shutdown();
```

UPDATE
Спасибо @Miron says reinstate Red Star за предложение добавить в конструктор нашего класса возможность изменять приоритет.

Полностью класс `MyParallelClass` выглядит так:

```
class MyParallelClass implements Runnable {

    public MyParallelClass(int priority) {
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(priority);
    }

    public MyParallelClass() {}

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " " + Thread.currentThread().getPriority());
    }
}
```

А также метод `main`, из которого мы все это запускаем:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    int yourPriority = 7; //min priority = 1, max = 10

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        service.execute(new MyParallelClass(yourPriority));
    }

    service.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: я бы еще в конструкторе приоритет указывал - приоритет по стандарту == 5